# COM CLASS Library . ASP.net MVC DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, registry

Is there a way to make a COM or Interop work on IIS Server Deployed ASP.net MVC?

I created an **MVC Site** which have a reference to a custom maid Interop  COM to a scanner machine.

It works on Debug mode on VS but, when I try to deploy it on IIS and access it. It gives me `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {3FEDB614-C25B-448C-AED3-2D38A6C95765} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`

The Thing is, the dll it self is already **installed** on my Machine, I think it is working on debug mode cause the IIS from VS is running differently or because I have a reference of the DLL needed.

But in IIS Deployment. Error Occurs. Any Ideas?

My main goal here is, to run the site on a Local Network and everyone can communicate with that site that has the Scanner Installed on.

Easy Idea, but hard implementation for me. And I am not even sure, if the call that I am doing is going to be made in the Host, rather than the Client.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty much it - you need to install your unmanaged COM dll (scanner software?) on the target computer where IIS runs.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like IIS application `Bin` folder doesn't have Interop dll, copy the Interop dll, it's named as `Interop.[YourCom].dll`. `YourCom` is nothing but original COM. So if the COM name is `MyCom.dll`, so Interop  should be `Interop.MyCom.dll`. If it's working on Debug mode on VS, then it should be available in VS application Bin folder.

Prerequisite of Interop dll: COM should be register in same the system.

Comment: thanks for pointing this Maiti, I will vote it up cause it may lead other that is having the problem as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

It ends up that, Even Registering it Manually, doesn't Help in my case, don't ask I HAVE NO IDEA WHY.

I resolve it by letting the VS studio Project Settings/Build Tab/ `Register COM` check mark do the Rest. But the trick is to Run VS in Administrator or you will have an error. Last step is right clicking the bin Folder and choosing add to project. Not really sure why it didn't work without it, because I am pretty sure it doesn't need to be in the current project since IIS will redirect anyway in the bin folder.

Interop name is already applied but like Maiti says, it is needed.